Turning $\left(\vec v\cdot\frac{\vec d}{\|\vec d\|}\right)\frac{\vec d}{\|\vec d\|}$ into $\left(\frac{\vec v\cdot\vec d}{\|\vec d\|^2}\right)\vec d$
Can someone please show me baby-like steps on how to re-arrange the equation on the right into the equation on the left:
$$\left(\vec{v}\cdot\frac{\vec{d}}{\|\vec{d}\|}\right)\frac{\vec{d}}{\|\vec{d}\|} \;=\; \left(\frac{\vec{v}\cdot\vec{d}}{\|\vec{d}\|^2}\right)\vec{d}$$

what definitions and properties do you know?

Remember that the dot product is linear and that the norm of a vector is a scalar

This is simply $\frac{a}{b}\frac{1}{b}=\frac{a}{b^2}$.
